Bollywood Horror movie
I watched this movie when I was younger around 2005-2010. I generally dislike Bollywood movies(only seen a handful and dances and songs really grind my gears) but this one was actually quite decent. It was set over the course of one night only and it was set in a house. There was a girl in the house alone by herself and she hears on the news that a mental patient escaped the asylum. It’s all dark and stormy(typical) but it really sets the mood. A guy that looks really ragged turns up the door that needs help and she lets him in. The whole movie you think the guy is the mental patient but in the end it turns out the girl is actually the mental patient. I cut it short but it had some really good scenes in it. IT only had those two characters in it( and a policeman I think) and had decent production value like a post 2000 film.

Removed the last part because it makes it a list question.

Is it Kaun
The film features a man claiming to be a white collar worker (Bajpai) and another man claiming to be a police inspector (Singh), both attempting to get into the house of a young woman (Matondkar). The film is considered to be one of the best collaborations between Ram Gopal Varma and Urmila Matondkar and is touted to be one of the best thriller's of Indian cinema. The film has since received cult status.

This is exactly the movie I was loooking for! Thanks
